# change look and feel of JFileChooser in swing

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

My requirement is to add check box with every directory which is shown by JFileChooser.
and give multi selection facility.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFileChooser with tree and check box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274668/jfilechooser-with-tree-and-check-box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be easier to implement a custom component than alter a `JFileChooser` to support this (odd) requirement.  You might start with altering the component used in [File Manager questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-manager-questions).

Answer (score 3):

`JFileChooser` has multi-selection built in ([setMultiSelectionEnabled()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29)). It doesn't use checkboxes, but you can select multiple items.

Comment: i know this one but i need multi selection with check box. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be done this way. Override `MetalFileChooserUI.createList()` and return your own custom list panel. Therein, add checkbox renderers to the items in your list.